# jooq code generation mysql remote db maven

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc, jooq

When I try to generate code against my remote DB, I keep getting some variation on the below:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.11.5:generate (default) on project vaadinwebsite: Error running jOOQ code generation tool: Communications link failure
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. Operation timed out
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This is in Eclipse or from the command line.  I know I can connect to this DB from this machine because I added it as a data source in Eclipse.  Adding -X and -e did not really tell me much.  How do I find out what the problem is?

Comment: How fast is the connection between your client workstation and the database? E.g. do you have some significant lag between the two?

Comment: Good question.  Not entirely sure, to be honest.  But I finally gave up and just decided to create a jar directly on my server ( so no remote access, same network ), and that worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Jooq code generation plugin needs to connect to DB server during its work to read schema definitions and generate java code based on these definitions.

The mistake is obvious here: **The driver has not received any packets from the server. Operation timed out**

So its a network issue

For debugging purposes and to eliminate credential related issues consider giving it wrong credentials just to see that it fails with a different error (the chances it will do so).

I can say that in my job we indeed work with a locally installed database in a similar case and have never seen issues like this.

Comment: Thanks.  What is weird is that, as per my post, I can access the database via Eclipse.  As per my answer to Lukas' question, I decided to go a different route and do it directly on the same server as the DB, creating a library jar.  That part worked ( after I fixed some timezone issues ).  But if I ever want to bring it closer to my application, as part of that build cycle, I will definitely try your bad credentials idea.  Worth a try.